# How to create an Object from a Generic class in C++?

Tags: c++

I wrote a class which take two components, an random class type T and an integer, I implement it like following:
In Test.h like:

```
    template <class A, int B>class Test { // two components, 
    private: 
        A first;
        int second;

    public:
        Test();
        Test (A,int);
    }
```

In Test.cpp I did:

```
    template <class T,int i> Test<T,i>::Test() {}
    template <class A,int i>Test<A,i>::Test(T a, int b):first(a) {second=b;}
```

**But in Main function:**

```
    Test<int, int >  T1; //It can not be passed
    Test<int, 4> T2; //It can not be passed 
    int x = 8;
    Test<int, x> T3 (3,4);// can not be passed
```

How I can declare an object instance from the above generic class?

Comment: Sigh.  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.15.

Comment: The proper term is "class template". The word "generic" is a bit dangerous in this context, because it has a very different meaning in other languages.

Comment: How i can declare an object from the Test class ? This is the question. Dude, I need it.... Please

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the semicolon at the end of the class template definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class T,int i> Test<T,i>::Test() {}
template <class A,int i>Test<A,i>::Test(T a, int b):first(a) {second=b;}
```

You need to put these two template function definitions in the header rather than the `.cpp` - the actual code needs to be made available to all compilation units that call these functions, not just the declaration.

```
Test<int, int >  T1; //It can not be passed
```

This is invalid, the second `int` is a type, but the template expects an `int` value

```
Test<int, 4> T2; //It can not be passed
```

There's nothing wrong with this

```
int x = 8;
Test<int, x> T3 (3,4);// can not be passed
```

You need to make the first of these lines `static const x = 8` (i.e. make `x` a compile-time constant) to make it a usable as a template parameter

And there's also the missing semicolon at the end of the class definition.

Comment: @user1314029 with what error? it works for me after fixing the other errors

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Test<int, 4>::Test()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @user1314029 ah, i missed the fact that you had your constructors in a `.cpp` file. Updated my answer.

Comment: To be pedantic.. `Test<int, 4> T2;` could be *compiled*, but it cased an error when linking.

Comment: @user1314029 see my updated answer - move the constructor code to the header file

Comment: I did, It gives me a new error, "No matching Constructor for intialization Test<int, 4>"... God...

Comment: @user1314029 Best update the question with current code... that'd only happen if you've somehow removed the no-arg constructor